# DBCP + HSQL on Spring is hanging while connection is being fetched

Tags: java, spring, database-connection, hsqldb, apache-commons-dbcp

How fix global stop, I mean, application run not ended, but it is hanging with next message (I have no break points)

```
 DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
```

properties file

```
connection.driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
connection.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test
connection.userName=sa
connection.password=

connection.pool.maxActive=1
connection.pool.initialSize=1
```

dependencies

```
def springVersion = '4.2.5.RELEASE'
dependencies {
compile 'org.hsqldb:hsqldb:2.3.1'
         'commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4',
         "org.springframework:spring-core:$springVersion",
         "org.springframework:spring-beans:$springVersion",
         "org.springframework:spring-context:$springVersion"//...
```

connection pool

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${connection.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${connection.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${connection.userName}" />
    <property name="password" value="${connection.password}" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="${connection.pool.initialSize}" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="${connection.pool.maxActive}" />
</bean>
```

Comment: check connections with your database and see if there are not already enough connections.

Comment: @java8.being, it is a clean start of DB.

Comment: I will recommend then you check for maxTime, set the property to 1000 to see if pool is exhausted of threads. Also, I will recommend you adding max to 2 instead of 1. What's the point of creating connection pool with 1 connection at a time?

Comment: @java8.being, Invalid property 'maxTime' of bean class [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource], also tried maxWait and initialSie=2 with maxActive=2 - same result. Mentioned config worked for JUnit with Maven, but now I have Spock + Gradle and something is broken.

Comment: I don't think if it has anything to do with Spock & Gradle.

Comment: Can you compare the .jar or .war or .ear file generated by Spock & Gradle vs it was generated by JUnit & maven?

Comment: We had a similar issue and we added maxActive=-1 and initialSize=-1 to the connection properties for the pool, that worked ("The maximum number of active connections that can be allocated from this pool at the same time, or negative for no limit.") - https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html